# LinQ to SQL - InsertOnSubmit without SubmitChanges

Tags: linq-to-sql

Suppose that I inserted an entity to an entity set by calling the **InsertOnSubmit** method , like this :

```
DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();
Product product = new Product {ID = "1" , Name = "Chair"};
db.Products.InsertOnSubmit(product);
// db.SubmitChanges();
```

I didnt call **SubmitChanges** intentionally .
My question is , can i later find that product and delete it with **DeleteOnSubmit** method?:

```
Product product = db.Products.Single(p => p.ID == "1");
db.Products.DeleteOnSubmit(product);
```

If i cannot , then what the **InsertOnSubmit method actually does**?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InsertOnSubmit method adds the entity to a list of entities which will be inserted when you call SubmitChanges.

> My question is , can i later find that product and delete it with DeleteOnSubmit method?:

You won't be able to find the entity because it does not exist in the database.

Note, if you leave out the find, ie if your code was

```
DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();
Product product = new Product {ID = "1" , Name = "Chair"};
db.Products.InsertOnSubmit(product);
db.Products.DeleteOnSubmit(product);
```

Then this would work as it wouldn't go near the database. The DeleteOnSubmit command would remove `product' from the list of entities to be inserted when you call SubmitChanges.